# "low disk space" in iCloud warning while there is 45GB free space

Tags: icloud, photos

I have 45GB free memory space on iCloud:

[image]

but when I try to upload my photos to iCloud, there is a warning: `low disk space`.

[image]

Why? It cannot be uploaded because of the incorrect warning message.

Comment: The low disk space message is referring to your device, not iCloud. How much free space you have on your device?

Comment: @tubedogg you are right... I never thought about it